# Where can I find the standard enthalpy of formation for Sodium Cyanamide (Na2NCN)?

Tags: enthalpy, reference-request

I am trying to find the standard enthalpy of formation for sodium cyanamide. Ive looked on various databases that list data about specific compounds but I can't find anything on this particular one. Where should I be looking?

Comment: [Cyanamide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanamide) is a known compound, $\cf{CN2H2}$.  The NIST Chemistry WebBook [contains](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C420042&Mask=2#Thermo-Condensed) information on its enthalpy of formation.

[Sodium cyanide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_cyanide) is a known compound, $\cf{NaCN}$.  The same source [also has](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C143339&Mask=2#Thermo-Condensed) has information on sodium cyanide's standard enthalpy of formation.  It is much tougher to find information on monosodium or disodium cyanamide!